# Proof Verification: A theorem on continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

Theorem: Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at a point $c \in A$. Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists
a neighborhood $V_{(\delta)}(c)$ of $c$ such that if $x, y \in A \cap V_{(\delta)}(c)$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Proof: Since $f$ is continuous at $c \in A$ then, $ \forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists \delta_{1} >0$ such that if $x \in A$  and $|x-c|<\delta_1$then $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon/2$

Similarly, $ \forall \epsilon >0$,  $\exists \delta_{2} >0$ such that if $y \in A$ and $|y-c|<\delta_2$then $|f(y)-f(c)|<\epsilon/2$

Choose $\delta = min({\delta_{1}, \delta_{2}})$

Then $-\epsilon/2 < f(x)-f(c) <\epsilon/2$

Implies $-\epsilon<f(x)-f(c)-(f(y)-f(c))<0$

Implies $-\epsilon<f(x)-f(y)<0$

Implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

Can anyone please verify this proof and let me know if it is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Your first line in the proof is odd (Perhaps $x$ has to satisfy $|x-c|<\delta_1$?) Also I don't understand what's the difference between the theorem and the definition of continuity.

Comment: Apologies, I missed out on $|x-c|<\delta_{1}$. Will edit my post right now.

Comment: Is the proof ok now though? Also, I think it's just an equivalent statement for continuity. Can you verify it?

Comment: You begin fine, but you don't need $\delta_1,\delta_2$ they're basically equal (there's no difference between $x$ and $y$ they're just variables). the first "implies" is wrong, the upper bound can't be zero, it should be $\varepsilon$. Other than that it's all good.